# Cucumber and Jacoco

Tags: cucumber, jacoco-maven-plugin

I got this error when I am using cucumber, maven-surefire-plugin, maven-failsafe-plugin and jacoco in my project and running test by maven.

Can anyone help me fix this issue?

```
org.sonar.java.jacoco.JacocoController$JacocoControllerError: Looks like several tests executed in parallel in the same JVM, thus coverage per test can't be recorded correctly.
    at org.sonar.java.jacoco.JacocoController.onTestStart(JacocoController.java:58)
    at org.sonar.java.jacoco.JUnitListener.testStarted(JUnitListener.java:42)
    at org.junit.runner.notification.SynchronizedRunListener.testStarted(SynchronizedRunListener.java:49)
    at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier$3.notifyListener(RunNotifier.java:121)
    at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier$SafeNotifier.run(RunNotifier.java:72)
    at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier.fireTestStarted(RunNotifier.java:118)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.EachTestNotifier.fireTestStarted(EachTestNotifier.java:42)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.JUnitReporter.result(JUnitReporter.java:103)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:310)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExecutionUnitRunner.run(ExecutionUnitRunner.java:102)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:63)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:18)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:70)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:95)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:38)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.run(Cucumber.java:100)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
```

The pom settling is like that:

```
           <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
              <configuration>
                <argLine>${jacoco.agent.ut.arg}</argLine>
                <properties>
                  <property>
                    <name>listener</name>
                    <value>org.sonar.java.jacoco.JUnitListener</value>
                  </property>
                </properties>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
              <configuration>
                <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m ${jacoco.agent.it.arg}</argLine>
                <properties>
                  <property>
                    <name>listener</name>
                    <value>org.sonar.java.jacoco.JUnitListener</value>
                  </property>
                </properties>
                <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
              </configuration>
              <executions>
                <execution>
                  <id>integration-test</id>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                  </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                  <id>verify</id>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>verify</goal>
                  </goals>
                </execution>
              </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
              <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>0.7.6.201602180812</version>
              <executions>
                <execution>
                  <id>prepare-ut-agent</id>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                    <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</destFile>
                    <propertyName>jacoco.agent.ut.arg</propertyName>
                    <append>true</append>
                  </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                  <id>prepare-it-agent</id>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                    <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.itReportPath}</destFile>
                    <propertyName>jacoco.agent.it.arg</propertyName>
                    <append>true</append>
                  </configuration>
                </execution>
              </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation with Jacoco and Cucumber, I added in my test-demo (mini) project the **'module3'**. Module3 gives you an concrete implementation /  answer to your question. See the [sipmle test-demo project](https://github.com/johan974/maven-multi-module-unittest-integrationtest-jacoco.git).

In the parent.pom you find the plugins for the tests (failsafe and surefire) and code coverage (jacoco). In the module3 I have put the Cucumber tests in a seperate folder. Via the builder-helper plugin the Cucumber tests are marked as tests. You could move those Cucumber tests (including steps, features) to a test folder. This way, you can seperate them from other regular tests.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)